# get pure name form an URL

Tags: php

I use this function to get basename of an URL

```
function get_domain($url)
{
  $pieces = parse_url($url);
  $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
  if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
    return $regs['domain'];
  }
  return false;
}

print get_domain("http://mail.somedomain.co.uk"); // outputs 'somedomain.co.uk'
```

But how can I get pure name without '.co.uk' or '.com' or anything else?

for example: **somedomain** without **co.uk**

I know I can remove manual via `str_replace($old, $new, $string)` ... but Is there not a better method?

Comment: you can use parse_url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get what you want:

```
$url= "http://mail.somedomain.co.uk";
$parts = parse_url($url);
$hostParts = explode('.',$parts['host']);
$main = $hostParts[1];
echo $main;
```

However, this will always give you the second part of domain. So, if you have a URL like `http://somedomain.com/` the output will be `com`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = explode('.', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
 echo $array[1];
```

**OR**

if URL Is dynamic than try this.

```
$array = explode('.',$url);
     echo $array[1];
```